# BJT based mutivibrator pspice simulation in CADENCE ORCAD

Tags: simulation, pspice, multivibrator

[image: BJT based multivibrator]

I am trying to simulate a basic BJT based multivibrator circuit in cadence orcad pspice. However, I am not getting the desired output.

If I simulate the same circuit in NI multisim, I am getting the desired output.

Do we need any specific simulation settings in ORCAD in order to view the output?

**update:**

I have tried the recommendation. However, unfortunately, there is no oscillation at the output. Please find below the schematic and output results.[image]

[image]

Comment: Well, there's a potentially useful answer below, but really you should detail what you mean by "I am not getting the desired output".

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with your particular taste of SPICE (pun intended), but this is actually a very fun and well-known example about simulated vs. real circuits.

Solution: Your circuit is in *perfect* symmetry, and thus, it won't start. Try 150.001 nF or 82.001 kΩ for *one* capacitor or resistor, and chances are it will kick into oscillation.

As long as you keep the symmetry, both transistors will "come to action" in *exactly* the same way, and the circuit won't start to oscillate.

(It won't oscillate in LTspice either, for example - and maybe there is some rounding error in multisim that will start the oscillation. LTspice even has this circuit in the demos that are provided with the download, and it has one 100k resistor and one with 101k, IIRC.)

A real circuit will never have exactly the same components twice, so it will start to oscillate with no problem. It's very educating that  *imperfections* are an absolute requirement for one of the most well-known basic circuits in electronics to work at all.

Answer (score 1):

Real (physical, non-simulated) oscillator circuits start because there is always noise in the circuit which gives gives small variations here and there which get amplified (because an oscillator has positive feedback) ant this starts your oscillator.

Simulated circuits have no noise when simulated in the time domain (transient simulation) so they tend to end up in a balanced state where it's all "ready to go" but there's no disturbance the kickstart it !

The solution is te provide that kickstart, I usually add a current source which inserts a small current pulse shortly after startup. In your case a small pulse at 0.1 s would do nicely. Make it a 1 mA pulse of 1 ms and inject it at the base of Q1 or Q2. Except for that short pulse the injected current must be 0 (zero) so it will not affect your circuit.

Oh, you migh also want to set the maximum timestep the simulator takes to 1/1000 th of the total time so that it calculates at least 1000 points. So in your case max timestep = 1 ms. Some simulators don't "see" the oscillation if you don't set the timestep small enough.

No simulate ! Success guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

PSPICE has very handy time-controlled switches (be careful, they're not perfect switches they turn on smoothly so the sim converges).

Try switching one of the resistors in with a switch that closes a few microseconds after t=0. Or change the resistors to be a bit different from each other and apply power through such a switch.  It's really not uncommon to have this kind of circuit fail to operate in simulation because the simulated parts are perfectly symmetrical.